# Nested RecyclerView like Google Play Store App

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on replicating the UI pattern implemented in the Play Store App. For implementing such a behavior, I have used a Vertical `RecyclerView` as outer view and added a horizontal `RecyclerView` inside the adapter of the outer Vertical `RecyclerView`.

The problem I am currently facing is while the outer `RecyclerView` is scrolling, the inner horizontal `RecyclerView` cannot catch the scroll event on it, but when the outer `RecyclerView` is not scrolling, we can scroll the horizontal `RecyclerView` smoothly.

If any one can be helpful please leave your comment. Cou can test the functionality in the Play store it enables the scroll of inner horizontal `RecyclerView`, even if the outer `RecyclerView` is scrolling.

Play store app:

[image: link to the image]

Comment: for the horizontal posts they use a viewpager

Comment: no they don't, if you use it you can see the scroll bar on the extreme left and right of the horizontal recycler view

Comment: @ArslanSohail Have you found the solution. I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: no solution i found uptill now :)

Comment: @ArslanSohail 5 years later, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's [a tutorial](http://khmertechtrain.tk/index.php/2017/10/03/create-a-vertical-scroll-and-horizontal-scroll-app-like-google-play-store/) for implementing such `RecyclerView`. You might also consider looking at the [github repository](https://github.com/Ranjan101/RecyclerView-Google-Play) as well.

The idea is to disable the touch detection of the outer `RecyclerView` when the inner `RecyclerView` is touched. See the implementation [here](https://github.com/Ranjan101/RecyclerView-Google-Play/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/rubensousa/recyclerviewsnap/SnapAdapter.java) in the parent `RecyclerView` adapter class.

```
// Disable touch detection for parent recyclerView if we use vertical nested recyclerViews
private View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
};
```

And then set the touch listener to the view.

```
view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView).setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
```

Comment: If the touch event is intercepted, requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent will never even get called as the touch has already been handled by the parentview, isn't it?